# scrletter change header and footer

Tags: scrletter

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ofoot{A}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{- \thepage\ -}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
page1
\newpage
page2
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The header and footer seems to have no effect. Probably because it is overwritten by scrletter?
If I removed the letter environment, the defined pagestyle would be active

Comment: Yes, the letter uses a `plain.letter` style. IIRC you can override it with `\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{}`. Note also that putting `\ofoot` before changing the page style and clearing it will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you. That worked

Answer (score 2):

First of all: If the result should be a letter with a first letter page, you have to use **`\opening{...}`**! Then you will get a warning because of the empty mandantory argument in `\begin{letter}{}`. To avoid this warning use `\begin{letter}[addrfield=false]{}` if there is no recipient.

---

The **second, third etc. page of the letter** uses the page style saved in **`\letterpagestyle`**. By default this is `plain.letter`. You can redefine both styles `plain.letter` and `letter` by

```latex
\renewpairofpagestyles{letter}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles%
  \ofoot*{A}
  \chead*{\pagemark}
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrletter}% loads scrlayer-scrpage and sets page style scrheadings automatically
\renewpairofpagestyles{letter}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles%
  \ofoot*{A}
  \chead*{\pagemark}
}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{- \thepage{} -}}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}[addrfield=false]{}%<- option addrfield=false added, because there is no recipient given
\opening{Hello}% <- added!!
\Blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could redefine `\letterpagestyle` in the preamble to a page style of your choice. If `\letterpagestyle` is empty, then the page style of the document is used on these pages too.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrletter}% loads scrlayer-scrpage and sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot{A}
\chead{\pagemark}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{- \thepage{} -}}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% <- page style of the second, third etc. page of the letter

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}[addrfield=false]{}%<- option addrfield=false added, because there is no recipient given
\opening{Hello}% <- added!!
\Blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

The **first letter page** uses page style **`empty`**. If you want to use an other page style on the first letter page, you have to add `\thispagestyle{...}` next to `\opening{...}`. If this page style defines a page header, you have to add KOMA option `firsthead=false` to disable the default first page header.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrletter}% loads scrlayer-scrpage and sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot{A}
\chead{\pagemark}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{- \thepage{} -}}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% <- page style of the second, third etc. page of the letter

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}[
  addrfield=false,%<- option addrfield=false added, because there is no recipient given
  firsthead=false% <- disable the default header of the first letter page
]{}
\opening{Hello}% <- added!!
\thispagestyle{\letterpagestyle}%<- change page style of the first letter page
\Blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]