# scrletter/scrlttr2 footer position and format

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlttr2

Using `scrletter`, I cannot get the exact same footer as on the first page (position and text). Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
headlines=8.1,
headheight=3cm,
footlines=1.1,
footheight=2cm,
parskip=full,
british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[a4paper,
%    %showframe,
rmargin=2cm,
marginparsep=0cm,
marginparwidth=0cm,
footskip=1cm,
lmargin=2cm,
bmargin=2cm,
tmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[%
foldmarks=false,
fromalign=right,
fromrule=off,
refline=dateleft,
fromphone=false,
fromemail=true,
pagenumber=footright,
fromlogo=false]{scrletter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pdflang=en-GB]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    %pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    %pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\thepage of \letterlastpage}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\raggedleft \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\rofoot{\usekomavar{nextfoot}}
\refoot{\usekomavar{nextfoot}}

\setkomavar{myref}[Internal \#]{Testref1234}
\setkomavar{date}[Date]{\today}
\setkomavar{yourref}[Your \#]{Testref5678}
\setkomavar{fromname}{A N Other}
\setkomavar{signature}{A N Other}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
    Building Number\\
    Street\\
    State\\
    ZIP Code%
}

\setkomavar{backaddress}{}
\setkomavar{subject}[]{\underline{Testing letter}}
\setkomavar{subjectseparator}[]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{%
            A. Person\\
            Someplace\\
            ZIP CODE%
        }
        \opening{test}
        \lipsum[1-4]
        
        \blindtext
        
        \lipsum[1-4]\footnote{\blindtext}
        \closing{cheers}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The `n of N` in the footer on every page after the first is italicized *and* does not match the distance from the bottom margin as on the first page. Also notice the footer is hidden in the long footer because of this.

Answer (score 4):

In your MWE you set `footskip=1cm` (distance between the text area and the baseline of the  footer) and `footheight=2cm` (height of the footer box). Therefore the footer overlaps the text area.

The first letter page uses page style `empty`. Header and footer on this page are positioned by pseudolength (see the KOMA-Script documentation).

There are some possibilities to get the same footer (same content and same position) on all pages, eg.

- Change the position of the footer layers for the page style used on second, third etc. page using the pseudolengths of the first page.
- Define a new layer using the pseudolengths of the first page and declare a new layer page style including this layer.
- Use page style `plain` on the first letter page. Then option `firstfoot=false` is needed to disable the default footer of the first letter page.
- etc.

Here are two examples for the third possibility:

1. `plain` as alias of `plain.letter`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  headheight=3cm,
  %footheight=2cm,% <- remove this!!
  parskip=full,
  british
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
margin=2cm,
marginparsep=0cm,
marginparwidth=0cm,
footskip=1cm,
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[%
  foldmarks=false,
  fromalign=right,
  fromrule=off,
  refline=dateleft,
  fromphone=false,
  fromemail=true,
  backaddress=false,
  subject=underlined,
  pagenumber=footright,
  firstfoot=false% <- added!
]{scrletter}% <- loads package scrlayer-scrpage automatically

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage[pdflang=en-GB]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=blue
}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of \letterlastpage}}% <- changed
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{plain}}% <- added

\setkomavar{myref}[Internal \#]{Testref1234}
\setkomavar{date}[Date]{\today}
\setkomavar{yourref}[Your \#]{Testref5678}
\setkomavar{fromname}{A N Other}
\setkomavar{signature}{A N Other}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Building Number\\Street\\State\\ZIP Code}
\setkomavar{subject}{Testing letter}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{A. Person\\Someplace\\ZIP CODE}
\opening{test}
\lipsum[1-9]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\closing{cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

2. `plain` as alias of `plain.scrheadings`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  headheight=3cm,
  %footheight=2cm,% <- remove this!!
  parskip=full,
  british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm,
  marginparsep=0cm,
  marginparwidth=0cm,
  footskip=1cm
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[%
  foldmarks=false,
  fromalign=right,
  fromrule=off,
  refline=dateleft,
  fromphone=false,
  fromemail=true,
  backaddress=false,
  subject=underlined,
  pagenumber=footright,
  firstfoot=false% <- added!
]{scrletter}% <- loads package scrlayer-scrpage automatically


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage[pdflang=en-GB]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=blue
}

\renewcommand*\letterpagestyle{}% <- added
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of \letterlastpage}}% <- changed
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{plain}}% <- added

\setkomavar{myref}[Internal \#]{Testref1234}
\setkomavar{date}[Date]{\today}
\setkomavar{yourref}[Your \#]{Testref5678}
\setkomavar{fromname}{A N Other}
\setkomavar{signature}{A N Other}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Building Number\\Street\\State\\ZIP Code}
\setkomavar{subject}{Testing letter}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{A. Person\\Someplace\\ZIP CODE}
\opening{test}
\lipsum[1-9]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\closing{cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For additional suggestions and information see also

- [scrletter change header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600629)
- [scrartcl / scrletter: applying pagestyle of firstpage to successive pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594156)
- [Pagestyle of KOMA letter package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299090)

---

**Update**:

If the page number must not be on the same vertical position on all pages, you can use `firstfoot=true` (default, eg. remove `firstfoot=false`) and KOMA-Script variable `firstfoot`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  headheight=3cm,
  %footheight=2cm,% <- remove this!!
  parskip=full,
  british
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
margin=2cm,
marginparsep=0cm,
marginparwidth=0cm,
footskip=1cm,
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[%
  foldmarks=false,
  fromalign=right,
  fromrule=off,
  refline=dateleft,
  fromphone=false,
  fromemail=true,
  backaddress=false,
  subject=underlined,
  pagenumber=footright
]{scrletter}% <- loads package scrlayer-scrpage automatically

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage[pdflang=en-GB]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=blue
}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of \letterlastpage}}% <- changed
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\raggedleft\pagemark}

\setkomavar{myref}[Internal \#]{Testref1234}
\setkomavar{date}[Date]{\today}
\setkomavar{yourref}[Your \#]{Testref5678}
\setkomavar{fromname}{A N Other}
\setkomavar{signature}{A N Other}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Building Number\\Street\\State\\ZIP Code}
\setkomavar{subject}{Testing letter}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{A. Person\\Someplace\\ZIP CODE}
\opening{test}
\lipsum[1-9]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\closing{cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @esdd. However, only using these statements are what were needed for me:

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\raggedleft \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}    
\renewcommand*\letterpagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of \letterlastpage}}
```

(2) nor the following didn't seem to be useful:

```
...
firstfoot=false
...
\clearpairofpagestyles
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

Comment: Then you use page style `empty` on the first letter page and  page style `plain.letter` on the next letter pages. Note the different height of the page numbers on the first letter page than on the other pages. You can uncomment either geometry option `showframe` or package `showframe` to visualize the different position. Additionally a different page style will be used outside the `letter` environment.